# How do you quit coffee?

Tags: health

I tried so many times, and sometimes succeeded for a few months even but then relapsed. Anyone ever successfully quit? If so, what's your secret?

Comment: Also, please see this relevant question: [How can I stay off coffee after I quit?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/how-can-i-stay-off-coffee-after-i-quit)

Comment: Why would you though? Drinking coffee has so many proven benefits. Scientific consensus on lots of health benefits of moderate coffee consumption (2-3 cups a day) is emerging rapidly.

Comment: Why would you want to quit?  Coffee is not that addictive. I was in China and basically was "forced" to give up coffee for a month.  After the first two days there was nothing to it.

Comment: As with most addiction quitting methods, try to wean yourself off of it. Keep a log of your coffee/caffeine intake every day and slowly decrease until you're at your desired intake.